# Interpolation of a huge 2D array in python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, interpolation

I've just plotted the following colormap from a 35x800 numpy array:
[image: colormap likelihood]

As you can see, the map appears crenelated: this is because cells contain probability = 0 (artefacts produced by model simulation method). I need to interpolate the data for (i) make a smooth and elegant colormap and (ii) obtain  the full matrix for follow-up computations. However, I don't know how to proceed and the interpolation method I should use. Any idea?

Comment: It's not that big! Is try the scipy bivariate spline routines to smooth it nicely. Then you have the spline function to recover or interpolate with, and can get derivatives as well.

Comment: Definitely recommend [`scipy.interpolate.interp2d`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp2d.html#scipy.interpolate.interp2d) like @JonCuster mentioned.

Comment: Try [scipy.interpolate.RectBivariateSpline](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.RectBivariateSpline.html) and specify a nonzero smoothing `s` parameter. Read the documentation of [bisplrep](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.bisplrep.html#scipy.interpolate.bisplrep) to understand what are useful `s` values. (interp2d is primarily for scattered data, and assumes s=0)

Comment: scipy.interpolate.RectBivariateSpline seems a good option. However, I don't know how to use it. My map is a variable called m with x rows and y columns. So i've tried interpolated_m = interpolate.interp2d (np.arange (0, len(m[:,0]), np.arange(0, len(m[0,:]), m, s = 3). However, the function returns a scipy.interpolate.fitpack2.RectBivariateSpline object that can not be entered as argument of pcolor(). Any help?